# Restkit - How to parse NSDate from NSString Unix timestamp?

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

Using Restkit for iOS, I'm getting a date as a unix timestamp.
The parameter is part of a response json and comes as string.

How can I make Restkit to parse it automatically to NSDate?

WebService json:

```
{"data":{"lastUpdate":""1374438771.27489"}}
```

Comment: What mapping have you tried so far and what is your destination object?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you. My destination object has NSDate as one of its ivars. The response comes as NSString. What mapping to use is exactly the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, let me share the solution with you.
Parsing Unix time from string to NSDate is done automatically in Restkit using its default formatters. The problem raised because I override the formatters when using `assignmentMapping.dateFormatters=dateFormatter`

The solution is to use `[RKObjectMapping addDefaultDateFormatter:dateFormatter];` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation:

https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Configuring-Date-and-Time-Mapping

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter  setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];
dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];

assignmentMapping.dateFormatters = [NSArray arrayWithObject: dateFormatter];
```

Comment: Yeah I got to this. This is a great page when the webService returns the date in a readable format. Which is not my case.